# Algorithm explanation for common strings

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

The Problem definition:

Given two strings a and b of equal length, what’s the longest string (S) that can be constructed such that S is a child to both a and b.
String x is said to be a child of string y if x can be formed by deleting 0 or more characters from y

*Input format*

Two strings a and b with a newline separating them

*Constraints*

All characters are upper-cased and lie between ascii values 65-90 The maximum length of the strings is 5000

*Output format*

Length of the string S

*Sample Input* #0

HARRY
SALLY

*Sample Output* #0

2

The longest possible subset of characters that is possible by deleting zero or more characters from HARRY and SALLY is AY, whose length is 2.

The solution:
`public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char[] a = in.readLine().toCharArray();
    char[] b = in.readLine().toCharArray();
    int[][] dp = new int[a.length + 1][b.length + 1];
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
           if (a[i] == b[j])
              dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j] + 1;
           else
              dp[i + 1][j + 1] = Math.max(dp[i][j + 1], dp[i + 1][j]);
              System.out.println(dp[a.length][b.length]);
  }
}`

Anyone has encountered this problem and solved using the solution like this? I solved it in a different way. Only found this solution is elegant, But can not make sense of it so far. Could anyone help explaining it little bit.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnD96abizww

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm uses [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The key point in understanding dynamic programming is to understand the recursive step which in this case is within the `if-else` statement. My understanding about the matrix of size `(a.length+1) * (b.length +1)` is that for a given element in the matrix `dp[i +1, j +1]` it represents that if the we only compare string `a[0:i]` and `b[0:j]` what will be the child of both `a[0:i]` and `b[0:j]` that has most characters.

So to understand the recursive step, let's look at the example of "HARRY" and "SALLY", say if I am on the step of calculating `dp[5][5]`, in this case, I will be looking at the last character `'Y'`:

A. if `a[4]` and `b[4]` are equal, in this case `"Y" = "Y"`, then i know the optimal solution is: 1) Find out what is the child of `"HARR"` and `"SALL"` that has most characters (let's say n characters) and then 2) add `1 to n`.

B. if `a[4]` and `b[4]` are not equal, then the optimal solution is either Child of `"HARR"` and `"SALLY"` or Child of `"HARRY"` and `"SALL"`  which will translate to `Max(dp[i+1][j] and dp[i][j+1])` in the code.